# Passing context/state to a SAML service provider

Tags: connected-apps, saml, identity

I'm using salesforce as an identity provider through a connected app link in my community. The service provider is a .NET application that downloads a lot of files. I've got the .NET application working with Salesforce as the identity provider using the sustainsys SAML2 library. Now I want to I'm trying to pass URL variables through the connected app, but nothing shows up in the service provider. The custom identity variables pass through on the identity object just fine.

```
https://{salesforceURL}?app={connectedAppId}&thisVar=123&otherVar=456
```

thisVar and otherVar are blank and the service provider URL is only

```
https://{serviceProviderURL}
```

What do I need to do to pass through URL variables using a connected app like this?

```
https://{serviceProviderURL}&thisVar=123&otherVar=456
```

Comment: Is your community a Salesforce community or an outside app? It would help to understand what you're trying to achieve (see [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: I added what the service provider does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sustainsys SAML library requires an attribute relayStateUsedAsReturnUrl="true" to be added to the web.config in order to return the RelayState on the URL. This configuration is not documented.

Answer (score 1):

In SAML, `RelayState` is used for passing state between identity and service provider. In identity provider-initiated flow, you construct the link by taking the value of `IdP-initiated Login URL` field from the connected app and appending `RelayState` to it as a query parameter.

- IdP-initiated Login URL is `https://blah.my.salesforce.com/idp/login?app=0sp...`
- IdP-initiated Login URL with RelayState is `https://blah.my.salesforce.com/idp/login?app=0sp...&RelayState=%2Fmy%2Fapp%2Fpage`

The value of `RelayState` should be URL-encoded. The interpretation of the `RelayState` and the resulting action is up to service provider. A typical implementation expects the `RelayState` to be a relative URI that tells the service provider to land the user on the certain page in your target application. The example above uses `/my/app/page` as the value.

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Comment: @afandre What is your expected versus observed result when you try this